# Is there a way to share my inventory to my friends?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have a few rares (and probably will have some legendaries later) for classes I don't play, which I'd like to make available to my friends, as they may be able to use them in their builds.

Is there a way to display items from my inventory with a link or something similar to the way you can look at other users' backpacks in Team Fortress 2? Or is my only option to write them down somewhere and direct them there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't share information about your inventory or stash automatically.  To let them know what you have, you need to manually link the items or let them know via some other means.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can't share the contents of your inventory or stash, you can link items to other players via whispers by shift-clicking the item in question. As for actually giving it to them, you'll need to join a game with them and either drop the item for them or trade it to them in town.